# Get value set in base class from child class instance in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, oop

I have a base class and a derived class as follows:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int a;
    public void Index() {
        a = 1;
    }
    public int Index1() {
        return a;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    //some derived class mehods
}
public class Main
{
    DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
    d.Index(); //this sets the value of a to 1
    //int i = d.Index1(); //returns 0
}
```

**Update**
controller.js

```
$http.get('/DerivedClass/Index1')
.success()
.error();
```

The class Derived class is a MVC controller class. 
The above js controller is an angular controller.
The js controller calls Index1 function of the derived class.

If I use static variable 'a' and then Index1() will return 1, but I don't want to use a static variable. Need any other solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The implementation of `Index1()` in the code you posted cannot possibly return null. It returns an `int`.

Comment: I doubt `Index1` returns `null` as `int` is not nullable. Actually it just returns zero, that´s not the same! Anyway without the code of your derived class we can´t say you what´s whrong.

Comment: I run the code you posted, an it's returning 1, not null.

Comment: I expect the error is in the "some derived class methods" which you're not showing us.

Comment: You are right. This is a modified code - similar(but not exactly the same) to my actual code. It will return 0. I dont want 0 to be returned. I want the set value. Updating the question, however with correctr value. Thanks.

Comment: looks like you return in `Index1` a different variable than you initialize in `Index`

Comment: The code you posted returns 1 as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFO6Tb

Comment: The problem is within your DerivedClass code, and as you didn't posted it, there is no way we can help you.

Comment: I still don´t see any code for your derived class, in particular how `Index1` is implemented. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: This is in fact a Javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

In that case if you don't care about incapsulation you can just access your BaseClass public field directly with following way:

```
  DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
  d.a = 1; //sets the value of a to 1
  var i = d.a; //gets the value of a field
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try and make a wild guess.

The first thing that comes to my mind is that you declared in the derived class a variable and a method with the same name:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int a;
    public void Index()
    {
        a = 1;
    }
    public int Index1()
    {
        return a;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int a;
    //some derived class mehods

    public int Index1()
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Now your problem becomes reproducible:

```
DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
d.Index(); //this sets the value of a to 1
int i = d.Index1(); // --> NOW it REALLY returns "0"
```

The Solution to this scenario would be either remove `public int a;` from the derived class, or call in the derived class:

```
public new int Index1()
{
    return base.a;
}
```